# Prolog infix operators of same precedence one xfy and the other yfx with two sequential operators

Tags: operators, infix-notation, iso-prolog

In trying to understand just infix operators of the type `xfy` and `yfx` with the same precedence and in sequence I see that there are just four combinations.

using

```
a = xfy  right-associative
b = yfx  left-associative
```

There is

```
aa  e.g. 1 xfy 2 xfy 3   e.g. 1 ^ 2 ^ 3
ab  e.g. 1 xfy 2 yfx 3  
ba  e.g. 1 yfx 2 xfy 3  
bb  e.g. 1 yfx 2 yfx 3   e.g. 1 - 2 - 3
```

Now for (xfy xfy) `aa` the operators are both right associative.
For (yfx yfx) `bb` the operators are both left associate.

However for (xfy yfx) `ab`  the (xfy) `a` operator is right associative and the (yfx) `b` operator is left associative. If I understand this correctly Prolog will evaluate this as:

Using a priority of `500` and `x` meaning `<` and `y` meaning `<=`

```
    xfy
    500
<500  <=500
  /     \
 1      yfx
        500
        / \
       2   3
```

and for (yfx xfy) `ba` I would expect

```
      500
      yfx
  <=500  <500
    /     \
  xfy      3
  500
  / \
 1   2
```

yet the ISO Prolog standard reads:

> An operand with the same priority as a left-associative operator which
>   precedes that operator need only be bracketed if the principal functor
>   of the operand is a right-associative operator.

With notation:

> An operand (xfy) `a` with the same priority (500) as a left-associative
>   operator which precedes that operator (yfx) `b`  need only be bracketed if
>   the principal functor of the operand (xfy) `a` is a right-associative
>   operator.

Did I understand this correctly? If so, why does (xfy yfx) `ab` need to bracketed while (yfx xfy) `ba` does not?

Also I looked for a practical example of two operators of the same precedence with one being xfy and the other being yfx, and only found one case for [Seed7 mult and tiimes](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Operator_precedence#Seed7). If one could provide a more practical example for `ab` and `ba` that would be appreciated.

EDIT

After reading the answer by [false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20693625/1243762) this is my understanding.

Since this is only about associativity, the rules using < and <= do not apply.
Instead we use the meaning of Y = Yes, X = No.

```
Unbracketed term  Yes/No                 Equivalent bracketed term
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 xfy 2 xfy 3     1 No|Yes 2 No|Yes 3    1 xfy (2 xfy 3)     ** right-associative
1 xfy 2 yfx 3     1 No|Yes 2 Yes|No 3    1 xfy (2 yfx 3)     ** this is a special!
1 yfx 2 xfy 3     1 Yes|No 2 No|Yes 3    --------------      ** invalid: noone wants association
1 yfx 2 yfx 3     1 Yes|No 2 Yes|No 3    (1 yfx 2) yfx 3     ** left-associative
```

EDIT

In looking for an example that has `xyf` and `yfx` of the same priority that makes sense I found [Meta-Interpreters](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci367s2c/resources/prologLectures/L17-Meta-Interpreters.pdf) which defines `op(500,xfy,<==).`

```
Valid
3 <==    1 +      2  
3 xfy    1 yfx    2  
3 No|Yes 1 Yes|No 2  

Invalid
1 +      2 <==    3
1 yfx    2 xfy    3
1 Yes|No 2 No|Yes 3

Valid and makes sense.
(1 + 2) <== 3
Prec 0  xfy Prec 0

Valid but does not make sense.
1       +  (2 <== 3)
Prec 0 yfx Prec 0
```

While the examples with parens are valid, it makes sense that you have to use parens to choose which one will make sense.

Comment: Would you mind replacing `a` by `xfy` and `b` by `yfx`? Such that we have the operator declarations `op(500,xfy,xfy), op(500,yfx,yfx)` The standard uses exactly such names. By introducing an extra level of indirection things do get quite confusing.

Comment: As for `op(500,xfy, <==)` I really doubt that anyone does rely on the precise priorities. Its more that 1200 would have required extra parentheses and so people switched.

Comment: Rules (that is, the rule atoms) have usually the highest precedence of 1200. And meta-interpreted rules are again rules. So they should rather have 1200 than 500.

Comment: That is definitely material for another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(The notation you use is extremely confusing to me, writing operators without operands, so I will stick to the standard-notation which always shows the operators plus the arguments.)

As for associativity — and this is all about it — there is a simple rule-of-thumb. Look at the `y` and `x` meaning Yes and No. `xfy` "says" on its left side `x`. So it does not "want" to associate with operators of the same priority. And on the right side, it "says" `y`, thus Yes I want to associate. When there are two operators that both say yes "to each other", it is the first occurring (when reading left-to-right) which takes the second as argument.  If you will, that case is handled like right associativity.

For this reason, with `op(500,xfy,xfy), op(500,yfx,yfx)` we have:

```
   Unbracketed term   Equivalent bracketed term
  -----------------------------------------------
    1 xfy 2 xfy 3        1 xfy (2 xfy 3)     ** right-associative
    1 xfy 2 yfx 3        1 xfy (2 yfx 3)     ** this is a special!
    1 yfx 2 xfy 3        --------------      ** invalid: noone wants association
    1 yfx 2 yfx 3        (1 yfx 2) yfx 3     ** left-associative
```

How well is that implemented? Look at [this comparison starting with #147](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#147) of a similar situation. So all except SWI implement reading correctly. But for writing, there are [some more systems](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#150) that do not conform.

I think this clearly shows that there is rarely a situation where Prolog programmers depend on this case. In fact, the standard operator table does not have any case related to this problem.

For a real example, consider `fy` and `yf` intended to denote some bracket-like syntax. In fact, in pre-ISO time several systems had `{` and `}` defined in such a manner to be used in DCG or CLP(Q). Please note, that those two operators cannot entirely simulate "bracketing". As an example, consider

```
   Unbracketed term   Equivalent bracketed term
  -----------------------------------------------
    fy fy 1 yf yf       fy (fy ((1 yf) yf)
```

On the other hand, if one has a term of the form `fy( fy(X) )` (note, it is in canonical syntax!), then `X` has to be either `(fy)/1` or `(yf)/1`. Any other term would have to be rejected.

Comment: @GuyCoder: As for examples: I'd say Prolog people rather try to avoid exploring all those corners.

Comment: Probably better to use the brackets if you need to dig this deep to figure it out.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Have you finished tokensyntax? There are only two, GNU and SICStus that handle it entirely.

Comment: @GuyCoder: I am referring to 6.4 Tokens. Tokens are special as the "eager consumer", "maximal munch" rule applies to them.

Comment: @GuyCoder: "tokenizing for each concept" - that sounds like a lot of retries. Prolog syntax is pretty independent of the concepts behind. I'd rather first write a full tokenizer. And then a reader. And then base the rest on it.